# Why is the dual exponent what it is?

Tags: functional-analysis

The dual $p'$ of an exponent $p \in [0, \infty]$ is:

$$p'= \begin{cases} \frac{p}{p-1}, & 1 < p < \infty \\
\infty, & p=1 \\
1, & p= \infty. \end{cases}$$

Why is this the dual of an exponent?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to write down an inequality

$$\|fg\|_1 \le C \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$$

for some $p, q$ and a universal constant $C$. The thing is that this inequality has to be **homogeneous**: dilations of $f$ shouldn't affect the inequality, nor should dilations of $g$ or dilations of the underlying measure. The fact that this is dilation invariant follows from the fact that $\|\lambda f\|_p = |\lambda| \|f\|_p$ for all $p$, which is why we take norms on both sides.

Dilating the **measure** gives us a relationship between $p$ and $q$. In particular, if we take $f = g = \chi_E$ to be the indicator of some measurable set, then the desired inequality reads

$$\mu(E) \le C \mu(E)^{1/p} \cdot \mu(E)^{1/q} = C \mu(E)^{1/p + 1/q}.$$

Now if $1/p + 1/q < 1$ and we have sets $E$ of arbitrarily large measure, there is no $C$ large enough to compensate for this and the inequality can't hold. Likewise, if $1/p + 1/q > 1$, we have a problem with sets of small measure.

So the happy medium is when $1/p + 1/q = 1$, which is exactly when $q = p'$. The moral of this story is that the full form Hölder's inequality can *only* hold with this choice of exponent, and that gives us the right dual space of $L^p$.

---

As a comment, homogeneity in various forms is a *wonderful* detector of false inequalities as well as a great predictor of true ones. It is one of my favorite techniques.

Comment: Is the dual of an exponent inherently tied to proving Hölder's inequality?

Comment: I'd say the more fundamental thing is the duality of $L^p$ and $L^{p'}$, which is in turn something that implies the full Holder inequality.

Comment: Is there some general definition for duality then? Since I've not seen similarities with the dual definitions.

Comment: The [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) is an object that comes up a lot.

Comment: But is the dual of an exponent some sort of dual space?

Comment: No, it's just a number that describes the dual space.